# How to embed JavaScript in C++?

Tags: javascript, c++

is it posible? i try this:

```
extern "javascript" {
```

b4 the function declaration s but it no work.why no?

Edit: it magicaly work now

Comment: Your gravatar looks... different

Comment: @Matti: it's about the nth time a newly created user named "Jon Skeet" asks a stupid question today. Like how to throw FORTRAN exceptions from JavaScript. @kid that likes to waste the time others are wasting on SO: Stop SPAMMING OUR SITE!

Comment: Try: `extern "magic" { doIt(); }`

Comment: @Martinho: Yes... I can clearly see it's a newly created user ￢_￢

Comment: @Martinho: It isn't *your* (or *our*) site ;-). That's just an illusion the actual owners want to give us :-)

Comment: You need to get the GNU GavaScript++ compiler.

Comment: It seems it magicaly work now.

Comment: Everyone go to Meta to see my post about this guy.

Comment: This is getting a bit boring now. Joke post requires more joke

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. However, you can include a JavaScript interpreter to your code to do that.
See. http://code.google.com/p/v8/

Comment: +1 for giving a sensible answer to a stupid question

Answer (score 1):

`extern` does not magically change the compiler into a JavaScript compiler, it only affects linkage-related stuff (name mangling etc)